# What does fs.writeSync(1, "a string") mean in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs

[From the docs:](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  fs.writeSync(1, `Caught exception: ${err}\n`);
});
```

Is `1` the stdout stream? I've read the docs for `fs.write` and there's no discussion of how to use an integer in the first argument. The [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L684) wasn't much help either.

I put this line

```
(require('fs')).writeSync(1, `Starting...`);
```

into my code, thinking it would go to stdout <strike>but there was no output like that when I started my app.</strike> and it did output.

OK now that I see it did actually work (output to console): where is this documented though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the `fs` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position)

> fs.writeSync(fd, buffer[, offset[, length[, position]]])

It's common to pass file handles around on Unix-derived systems using [nominal types like `FILE`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/), but in reality all files are represented and referenced by an unsigned integer called a *file descriptor* or `fd` (which can also refer to other types of open files, including pipes, FIFOs, sockets, terminals, devices)

In regards to where the argument of `1` comes from, all systems compliant with the [Single Unix Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification) inherit three such file descriptors when starting a shell, which processes spawned from that shell inherit.

- Descriptor 0 is *standard input*, the `fd` from which the process takes it's input.
- Descriptor 1 is *standard output*, the `fd` to which the process writes it's output.
- Descriptor 2 is *standard error*, the `fd` to which the process writes error messages.

All three of these are normally connected to the shell (and thus terminal emulator's) output.

Comment: FYI, node.js documents [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) as the file descriptor for stdout and I would think it preferable to use that instead of a hard coded number, particular if you ever want your code to be compatible with a non-Unix platform.  And, note that `fs.writeSync(process.stdout, 'Caught exception: ${err}\n');` is a lot more self documenting than `fs.writeSync(1, 'Caught exception: ${err}\n');`.

Comment: "node.js documents process.stdout as the file descriptor for stdout" -- solid point; I'm used to seeing process.stdout in the docs, not 1 or 2; that's why it threw me off; oh and I'm developing on Windows currently (it actually did work on Windows)

Comment: The `fs.writeSync` seems to force synchronous writes, compared to `process.stdout` where you have to deal with https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#a-note-on-process-io

Answer (score -1):

The docs absolutely do show an integer 'fd' as the first argument, I'm not sure why you say it doesn't. What number 1 means isn't covered in the Node docs beyond the statement that they're POSIX file descriptors.  That info is covered in Wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Comment: I meant there's no discussion of using 1 in the first arg. Doesn't explain how 1 is a special value. The other user explained it.